# Find first element of inverse matrix knowing Cholesky decomposition.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Given Cholesky decomposition of matrix A = LDL$^{T}$ = $A^{T}$ provide a possibly most efficient method to calculate upper left element of $A^{-1}$.
I was thinking that this could be solved by using Gaussian algorithms, but couldn't really get anything out of it.

Answer (score 6):

You want to compute 
$$
e_1^TL^{-T}D^{-1}L^{-1}e_1=(L^{-1}e_1)^TD^{-1}(L^{-1}e_1)
$$
which means you have to solve the lower left triangular system $Lv=e_1$ and then compute $v^TD^{-1}v=\sum d_k^{-1}v_k^2$.